# Python Compare Two Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the below condition in **web1.xslx** file

| Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | CBD |
| CBD | NCD |
| CBD | NCN |
| CBE | CBE |
| DHE | DHE |

I need to compare **Data1** and **Data2** and if both is equal then output in status as **OK** else **NOK** like below in separate excel sheet **web2.xslx** using Python Script

| Data1 | Data2 | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | CBD | NOK |
| CBD | NCD | NOK |
| CBD | NCN | NOK |
| CBE | CBE | OK |
| DHE | DHE | OK |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is named `df`, you could use:

```
df = pd.read_excel("web1.xlsx")
df['status'] = df['Data1'].eq(df['Data2']).map({True: 'OK', False: 'NOK'})
df.to_excel("web2.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('web1.xlsx')

status = []
for i in range (df.shape[0]):
    if (df.iloc[i,:][0] == df.iloc[i,:][1]):
        status.append('OK')
    else:
        status.append('NOK')

df['status'] = status
print(df)
```

Hope this helps your work, if it's correct please mark it as an answer. Thx

Comment: Looping over rows in pandas/numpy is highly inefficient. Use vector operations.

Comment: Hello Felix,
May I know what is the role of df.shape[0] in for loop?

Comment: @Moses df.shape[0] means it returns the total rows in your dataframe, so it iterate for each row in your df

Comment: @Moses you should really not use this approach, never loop over dataframes unless you know why or have no other choice

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).